# How to do "Indent to here" / "Hanging Indent" in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts

You can use "Indent to here" / "Hanging Indent" in InDesign by Command-Backslash.

Is there a way to do this in Illustrator without having to Tab to Indent or press the spacebar a few times?

This is what I'm looking for:

[image]

This was done in Illustrator. Because both the 2nd and 3rd bullet points are longer, it goes to the next line. I want to know if there's a way in Illustrator that you can make the word "over" line up with "dogs" above it (for the 2nd point), and the word "and" to line up with "dogs" above it (for the 3rd point).

I know I can cheat and use a soft return and press space bar till it lines up, but it's not the best way. I know in InDesign you press **Command + backspace** and it will line up the words.

Comment: While this is an Adobe Help Desk question, which we tend to close, it's a really *good* one, so I'm reluctant to close it. :)

Comment: Hi Lauren, I'm sorry, but why is this an Adobe Help Desk question? I think it's a legit question to ask as someone else might know an answer to which I don't. Please kindly explain? Thank you. :)

Comment: GDSE gets a *lot* of "how do you do X in Adobe Y?" questions, many of which can be answered by Googling tutorials. The community consensus is that many such questions, although not all, should be closed. This one is an exception, in my opinion, so I agree with you that it's legit. Google seems to say that the feature doesn't exist in IL, however.

Comment: Thanks Lauren for opening it up again. Prior to posting this question, I had already Googled it, but I found no answers, hence coming on the forums to ask.

Answer (score 7):

I used a negative value for the "First-line indent" it works like charm [image]

Answer (score 3):

not a 100% sure if this is what you're asking, but if it is, then yay! You can adust indents in the **Paragraph** panel. If this isn't what you're asking then please show me what you're talking about (screenshot) and I'll see if there's anything I can do.

[image: Indent]

Round 2: I don't think there is an easy shortcut like the one you mentioned, not that I'm aware of anyway (and I looked!) But, perhaps this could be of help:

[image]

Comment: Hi SentientEnergy, Please see my comment above. Thanks :)

Comment: Cool, I have one more suggestion (check above).

Comment: Thanks SentientEnergy. It seems that there isn't a simple command in Illustrator like how there is in InDesign. Looks like I still have to manually do it using tabs. Thanks again for all your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Just like InDesign.....

Select your text and bring up the **Tabs** window (`Window > Type > Tabs`).

Drag the bottom portion of the left marker inward. This is your "to here" mark. Then you can drag the top portion to the right to indent all the lines.

You do need to also set a left side tab in the same position as the bottom half marker in order to get the bullet spacing to line up. (This specific part is unlike InDesign).

[image]

Once you set this visually, you can then refine it via the **Paragraph Panel**. For me, it just helps to see it visually, then tweak numbers slightly if needed.

Answer (score 1):

My way : set left indent (example : 60pt) than create bullet from rectangle tools just copy paste them. Don't forget to activate "Show grid" to make sure the bullets are in line.

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback on SentientEnergy's solution, if you have a lot of text that you would like to apply hanging indents to, once you've edited the indent settings the way you'd like, it's advisable to create a paragraph style.
To do so, place your cursor in a properly styled paragraph and go to Window>Type>Paragraph Styles to open the Paragraph Styles panel. Click on the flyout menu in the upper right of the panel, choose New Paragraph Style…, name your style in the ensuing dialog, and click OK.
To apply the style to other paragraphs, select them and then click on the style name in the Paragraph Styles panel.

Comment: Thanks David. I shall have to check out Paragraph Styles. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use Type > Paragraph and give "First-line left indent" a negative value. This moves the bullet out of the text box and the rest is aligned. To get the text back inside the box, just add normal Left indent as much as you gave negative for the first line.

Comment: But then it could be you print outside the printing area ... BTW: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible in Illustrator, as it is in InDesign as well featured as a *Special Character* (*Type > Insert Special Character > Other > Indent to Here* – the effect is that the indent automatically adjusts if the text before it changes), not as a paragraph attribute, and Illustrator doesn't feature such special paragraph-adjusting characters. The easiest way to do it manually in Illustrator is most probably using the *Tabs* window and setting tabs manually to be as close as possible to the character. If you want to be pixel-perfect, you can copy the text before the indentation and paste it as a new Point Type text object (the one not having a text frame) and read its width, which you can now add as the tab stop position.

If you only need indentation for bullet points, however, it doesn't require this kind of action. Just adjust the *Left indent* as desired for the indented part of the text and add as much negative *First line indent* to adjust the bullet back in line with the text frame's left side. You can just select the whole text frame or even multiple text frames to adjust all bullets simultaneously. And as in InDesign, you can also create a *Paragraph style* out of it to keep all the text frame indentations perfectly same. Added bonus (or a drawback, depending on your needs) is that the indentation doesn't change if you use bullet points of different width (e.g. an en dash might be wider than a bullet is).

Unfortunately, in Illustrator you cannot create keyboard shortcuts for paragraph styles either, in contrast to InDesign, so when creating bulleted lists, you'll have to apply the style by selecting it with a mouse from the style list. Also, you cannot make the bullet itself as a paragraph style setting as you can in InDesign, so you'll always have to type the bullet itself in first. Copy-pasting of course handles the copying of the paragraph style and the bullet at the same time.

If the text is very long and complicated and you need to use the Indent to Here feature very often, there is always the option to do the text in InDesign and the drawings in Illustrator, and paste one on the another as PDF.

Answer (score 0):

To align the second line of text after a bullet, place your cursor before the first word after the bullet (in the first line of text) and use the shortcut Ctrl + backslash key.

Comment: Hey there Sue, welcome to GD.SE! Are you sure this solution works in Illustrator? It sounds like the original poster was expecting just what you've said to work (as it does in InDesign), but it didn't work for them... If you have any questions about how the site works, have a look at the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or feel free to ping one of us in [Graphic Design Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) once your reputation reaches 20. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

I've found if you copy the bullet and following space and paste it into the beginning of the following lines (with a soft return), then delete the bullet, the spacing seems to stay. Thus including the full tab width on each line.  Ideal for a short paragraph, but I understand if it's a huge list it could get tricky.

Not the tidiest fix from Illustrator, but it's the one I use.